# Instagram login with Python requests

Tags: python, web-scraping, automation, python-requests, instagram

I am trying to login to a Instagram account using Python requests. When I run the code below, I am getting HTTP 400 and my session cookies are returning as empty . How can I do this?

```
import requests


base_url = "https://instagram.com/"
login_url = base_url + "accounts/login/ajax/"
username = "user"
password = "pwd"
USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.61 Safari/537.36"

session = requests.Session()
session.headers = {"user_agent": USER_AGENT}
session.headers.update({"Referer": base_url})
req = session.get(base_url)
session.headers.update({"X-CSRFToken": req.cookies["csrftoken"]})
login_data = {"username": username, "password": password}
login = session.post(login_url, data=login_data, allow_redirects=True)
print(f"session cookies: {login.cookies}")
print(f"status {login.status_code}")
session.headers.update({"X-CSRFToken": login.cookies["csrftoken"]})
```

Comment: I do not know this specifically, but I think it very unlikely it will be possible to login to instagram with simple web requests. there is an API that you're supposed to use, and you can get access to any accounts you own. [see the last question in faq](https://www.instagram.com/developer/)

Comment: I can't use Instagram API, because there are a lot of limitations. I don't want to use Selenium too, because it is too slow.. I really think this is possible maybe with requests + bsoup.. But I am missing something... I ll keep searching.